Color Bands Not Running From 0 to 255 as Expected in RGB Tiff
There is a Colour Tiff in ArcGIS Pro. This is produced by an extract from a WMS Service of the Ordnance Survey 1:25k Explorer Map: https://ukmapcentre.com/explorer-maps-25000-scale/.
The extract is created by turning off all layers other than the WMS, then within Pro, Share -> Export Map GeoTiff - Map.
The output tiff is a multiband raster which shows three bands in the Table of Contents:

Individual Bands are exported using the Make Raster Layer tool (Data Management Tools -> Layers and Table Views -> Make Raster Layer). This shows four bands, the R, G and B bands and a fourth opaque band:

Each individual band is exported to be a new raster. The Red band goes from 4 to 102 and the Green and Blue bands go from 4 to 102.
However, the WMS export has multiple green and blue features. As such values higher than 102 are expected for both the G and B bands. For example, hydrology, shown as blue lines:

To investigate this further, the Get Cell Value tool (Data Management -> Raster Toolset -> Raster Properties) is used to get the value of the bands for a single cell of the hydrology feature:

This gives the following results:
Red: 47
Green: 83
Blue: 95
Band 4: 102
Entering these values into https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html gives a different colour:

I do not understand why the colours are different. What is the error in my understanding?

Not should reach 255 it's could include values up to 255, thre's no requirement to hit the max. If you want to increase the range you can export the raster with your current renderer https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/imagery/export-or-convert-raster-datasets.htm#:~:text=choose%20an%20option%20under%20Renderer%20Settings . Your raster is likely RGBA with the 4th band all 255 (opaque), you can use an alpha band in your display but if it's all opaque there's no real need.

And the values appearing to be higher than they are is likely because a stretch is being applied when rendering, check layer properties - symbology

Thank you for your reply. In the example given there are blue features in the raster, for which the value of the blue band should be much higher than 104, as per the example  values for the R, G and B bands as taken from https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html. What I am unclear on is how there are blue features in the raster where the blue band goes no higher than 104. This question exists for other features as well but the blue hydrology lines gives the clearest example.

The values are lower than expected, not higher. Separately I've expanded on the information by using the Get Cell Value tool and edited the question for clarity.
